# Google Earth API - time primitive set even though KML file has no time elements

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to load via Google Earth API a KML file and have my own time slider control.

To determine if I need to enable/display my own custom time slider I am interogating the google earth TimeControl to see if there are any begin and end times set.

If I load a KML with a timespan I am seeing that a begin and end time are set and the google earth time slider appears in google earth.

If I then load another KML file but this time without any timespan, google earth correctly does not display the time slider but when I interrogate the TimeControl through the google earth API it still has the start and end times of the first KML.

I have attached (via kmltree bind() method) a function which gets called once the KML has loaded. It is this function that I interrogate the TimeControl.

Why does the TimeControl still contain the start and end times of the first KML? Am I checking too early?

Javascript code is:

```
                tree = kmltree({
                        url: kmlUrl,
                        gex: gex,
                        element: $('.tree3'),
                        mapElement: $('#map3d'),
    setExtent: true,
                        restoreState: false
                });

$(tree).bind('kmlLoaded', function(event, kmlObject)
{
    console.log("In kmlLoaded function");

    time = ge.getTime();

    if(ge.getTime().getControl())
    {
        console.log("We have a time primitive.");
        control = time.getControl();
        extents = control.getExtents();

        // We have some time elements
        beginTime = extents.getBegin();
        console.log("beginTime is: " + beginTime.get());

        endTime = extents.getEnd();
        console.log("endTime is: " + endTime.get());

        mainwindow.enablePlaybackWidgets(beginTime.get(), endTime.get());
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("We do NOT have a time primitive.");
        mainwindow.enablePlaybackWidgets("", "");
    }
        });

                tree.load()
```

I am using this in conjunction with a QT app and upon finding out if there is a timespan within the new loaded KML or not, it sould then call in to the QT mainwindow object and enable/disable my custom time slider widgets accordingly.

When the second KML is loaded I am expecting there to be no TimeControl (as Google Earth is not displaying one) and hence enter the "else" part of the code above. This is not the case. The TimeControl still exists and has the start and end times from the first KML file loaded.

any help would be very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: You don't show how you are removing the first KML - you ARE removing the first KML aren't you?

Comment: yes I am removing the KML, or at least I think I am. I am using "kmltree" to handle the KML. When a new KML is loaded I first check to see if a kmltree already exists with the code below;

Comment: if(tree && tree.destroy)
    {
                                    tree.destroy();
        
        time = null;
        control = null;
        extents = null;
        beginTime = null;
        endTime = null;

        $('#tree' + counter).replaceWith('<div id="tree' + (counter + 1) + '" class="tree3" style="float:left; height: 210px; width: 200px; top: 0px; left: 0%; overflow-y:auto;"></div>');

                      counter = counter + 1;

Comment: @lifeIsGood I thought the "kmltree" was supposed to handle the loading and destroying of the KML plus also the rendering of the KML to the Google Earth map. Should I be removing/destroying the KML in a different way? Sorry for the code formatting in the previous comment!!!